# how to set the child-class height as per the parent div using css

Tags: css

i have three classes

```
 .wrapper
 {
    width: 100%;
    float:left;
    min-height: calc(100% - 80px );
    background-color: #2d3e50;
 }
 .menu
 {
    width:7%;
    float: left;
    background-color: #2d3e50;
    height: 100%;
 }
 .content
 {
    float: left;
    padding: 20px 5px 20px 1%;
    width:93% ;
    background-color: #ffffff; 
    height: 100%;
 }

 <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="menu"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
 </div>
```

the height of the "wrapper" is perfect as per the calculation but i want height of the "menu" and "content" class 100% as per the "wrapper" class in all browser "safari" ,"chrome" also. but not working properly please suggest me css for all browser the problem is putting here as image![enter image description here][1]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try it with `display: table` and `display: table-cell`.

Here is the [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LeFnx)

CSS

```
* {margin: 0} 
html, body {height: 100%}
.wrapper
 {
    display: table;    
    height: calc(100% - 80px );
    background-color: #2d3e50;
   width: 100%
 }
 .menu
 {
    display: table-cell;
    width:7%;
    background-color: #2d3e50;
    height: 100%;
 }
 .content
 {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 20px 0.5%;
    width:92% ;
    background-color: #ffffff; 
    height: 100%;
 }
```

Comment: with display table the calc(100%-80px) not working. if you can do then send me one example

Comment: Its working fine a my end http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LeFnx. Can you tell me which browser you are checking?

Answer (score 0):

Height in percentage would work only in IE not other browsers. For other browsers you should have a fixed height to your parent div.

Here is easy solution to make it work:

```
html,body{
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: already given not working this is. and also problem with safari

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS to .wrapper and .menu:

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

.menu {
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

and remove the

```
float: left;
```

from .menu. Does that give .menu a height of 100%?

If yes, then remove the

```
float: left;
```

from .content and add this to .content's CSS:

```
.content {
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

so it is my last suggesstion works fine in w3s tryit editor.
`<table class="wrapper"> <tr>

    <td class="menu"></td>

<td class="content"></td>

 </tr>
</table>`